# ProgressMonitorInputStream in Socket Programming

Tags: java, sockets, progressmonitor

I have a socket connected client and server. I tried to implement progressMonitorInputStream() to server, the data is transferred perfectly but the Progress Monitor is not visible. I tried implementing it for reading from a file only one side, there the progress monitor works fine. Below are both codes

> Server:

```
    public class Server implements ActionListener, PropertyChangeListener {

    DataInputStream dis;
    ProgressMonitor pm;
    ProgressMonitorInputStream pmis;
    JFrame frm;
    Server s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                new Server().createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        frm = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JButton st = new JButton("Start");

        st.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 25));

        panel.add(st);

        panel.setSize(500, 50);

        frm.add(panel);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.pack();
        frm.show();

        st.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frm.dispose();
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5555);
            Socket soc = ss.accept();
            dis = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
            pmis = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(frm, "Progress", dis);
            pm = pmis.getProgressMonitor();
//            pm.setMillisToPopup(1);
            Task task = new Task();
            task.addPropertyChangeListener(s);
            task.execute();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
            pm.setProgress(progress);

        }
    }

    class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            int progress = 0;
            setProgress(0);
            int x;
            while ((x = pmis.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) x);
                setProgress(progress);
                progress++;                
            }
            pmis.close();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void done() {
            pm.close();
        }        

    }
}
```

The above code is the problematic one. The working code is below:

> Proper working code with File Input Stream on one side

```
    public class ProgressMonitorOwn implements ActionListener,
        PropertyChangeListener {

    JFrame frm;
    Task task;
    DataInputStream dis;
    ProgressMonitorInputStream pmis;
    JButton but;
    ProgressMonitor pm;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ProgressMonitorOwn().createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        frm = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        but = new JButton("Show");
        but.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));

        panel.add(but);
        panel.setSize(200, 100);

        frm.add(panel);
        frm.setSize(200, 100);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.show();
        but.addActionListener(this);
    }

    class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            int x;
            int prog = 0;
            while ((x = pmis.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) x);
                setProgress(prog);
                Thread.sleep(100);
                prog++;
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        public void done() {
            but.setEnabled(true);
            pm.close();
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        but.setEnabled(false);
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\test\\test.txt");
            dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
            pmis = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(frm, "ProgressTest", dis);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        task = new Task();
        task.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
        task.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if ("progress" .equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
            pm = pmis.getProgressMonitor();
            pm.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out why Progress Monitor is displayed in FileInputStream Program but not on socket program. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setMaximum()` on the `ProgressMonitor` of the `ProgressMonitorInputStream` to the expected size of the download. Otherwise it doesn't know what 'progress' means.

You don't have to call `setProgress()` with a `ProgressMonitorInputStream`. It does that automatically.

You don't need the `DataInputStream.`

You should read more than a byte at a time. Read into a `byte[]` buffer.

Comment: I think we use ProgressMonitor for unknown sized files. Correct me if I am wrong. I tried without using setProgress(), it didn't work. I am transferring Strings so I use DataInputStream for readUTF(). If I read bytes converting string to byte[], I will have to convert them back right? For going through such process, I can easily transfer Strings using DataInputStream. I would like to know why you suggest using byte[] when we can transfer strings.

Comment: @Parthe I don't know what your first sentence means. I tried it with calling `setMaximum()` and without calling `setProgress()` and it did work. Your `DataInputStream` should be above the `ProgressMonitorInputStream` if you're going to call methods on it, otherwise the `ProgressMonitor` can't possibly be aware of any progress being made. I suggested calling `read(byte[])` rather than the one-byte `read()` which is all that your posted code exhibits. I can't comment on code you haven't posted.

Comment: I tried covering `DataInputStream` over `ProgressMonitorInputStream` but again the same problem occurred, Progress monitor did not display. I saw some links that had code with InputStreams covering `ProgressMonitorInputStream`. I copy pasted the code but the progress monitor did not display. If you know some working code you edited, please let me know and I understand what you mean by `read(byte[])`. I ll implement it.

Comment: I converted to `read(byte[])` but there is a new problem, the last 2 or there Strings comes with an extra 'e'.

Comment: If I remove `setProgress()` what would go in `propertyChange()`?

Comment: You don't need to call read(byte[]) if you're calling readUTF(). The code I got working is what you posted here with the modifications I suggested above.

Comment: And nothing 'goes in propertyChange()'. You don't have to do anything except set the maximum and read. I already said that.

Comment: That works thanks. But there is another problem, the progress bar ends before the contents are read. I think this problem occurs since I am converting file size in long to an int and passing it to `setMaximum()`. Any ideas on how to show progress bar till the end.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue unless the file is >= 2GB.

Comment: If the file is >= 2GB what should I do?

Comment: Good question. I don't have an answer, except to say that if you're downloading a file that big in front of a user it is probably futile to display progress at all, as it will take hours.

Answer (score 0):

Call `frm.setVisible(true);` to make is visible. Change in both the classes.

Remove `frm.show()` because it is a **deprecated method**. Look here [Component#show()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#show%28boolean%29).

Sample code:

```
private void createAndShowUI() {
   frm = new JFrame();
   ...
   // call in the end after adding all the components
   frm.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Tried that. No use. The frame I used in the Server class is just to show the "Start" button. I does nothing else and progress monitor doesn't have show() or setVisible(). My problem is that Progress Monitor is not displayed.

Comment: Look at `createAndShowUI()` method where you have created a `JFrame`

Comment: That frame contains only a button. It is shown without problem. Should I call setVisible too?

Comment: @Parthe What is your actual issue? as per your question you said **the Progress Monitor is not visible**

Comment: Yes the Progress Monitor is not visible. I tried calling setVisible(true). Nothing changed. The frame you are mentioning contains a panel which has a button that is it. I get the Progress Monitor from the ProgressMonitorInputStream, this has nothing to do with the JFrame.